# PHP return 0 records for today's date , but MySQL cli returns records

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to get today's records from `MySQL` , When i run this query in `MySQL` I get few (15) records , but when i run same query via `PHP` it return 0 records

query to get daily data :

```
   SELECT b.id,db.name,b.Deleted,b.ModifiedDate,b.Address1,
          b.Address2,b.city,b.state,b.zip,
          b.hours,b.Description,b.latitude,b.longitude 
   FROM businesses b 
      inner join bus_metrodb_xref bx on b.id = bx.bus_id_fk 
      inner join dbas db on db.bus_id_fk = b.id 
   WHERE bx.met_id_fk = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" 
     and (b.ModifiedDate) >= CURRENT_DATE 
   order by b.ModifiedDate DESC limit 15
```

PHP

```
$mainQue ="SELECT b.id,db.name,b.Deleted,b.ModifiedDate,b.Address1,
                  b.Address2,b.city,b.state,b.zip,
                  b.hours,b.Description,b.latitude,b.longitude 
           FROM businesses b 
              inner join bus_metrodb_xref bx on b.id = bx.bus_id_fk 
              inner join dbas db on db.bus_id_fk = b.id  
           WHERE bx.met_id_fk = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' ";

$durStr="";
$orderBy = "order by b.ModifiedDate DESC limit 15";

switch ($_GET['duration']) {
      case 'full':
    $durStr="";
    break;
    case 'daily':
    $durStr = "and (b.ModifiedDate) >=  CURDATE() ";
    break;
    case 'weekly':
    $durStr = "and b.ModifiedDate >=  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND  b.ModifiedDate <= CURDATE()";
    break;
      default:
    $durStr="";
    break;
}

$quee = $mainQue ." ".$durStr . " " . $orderBy;

    $rs=$DBH->query($quee); 
var_dump($rs);
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row['id'] ."<br />";
}
```

var_dump

```
object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null
```

same query on phpmyadmin.
[image]

*Tried `CURDATE()` , `CURRENT_DATE` and `now()` all of them shows records when run on mysql

** removing `(b.ModifiedDate) >= CURRENT_DATE` returns `15` records

[image]

Comment: Can you post your PHP code, which returning 0 records?

Comment: Use `now()` and remove `CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: Are there any error log in php log or mysql log?

Comment: @RuchishParikh Tried , same results .

Comment: @mbo no errors in both logfiles

Comment: Change to another sql which can undoubtedly get data to check whether the sql connect is ok or not

Comment: I am going to ask what might be considered a silly question **Are you sure you are looking at the same database in all these cases**?

Comment: @mbo if i remove date part i get records back to php.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yup 100% sure ;)

Comment: OK. If removing date part can get records then the question can be narrowed to the date part.  1)You can check the sql bin log to see what the real sql executed by php is.   2)Change the date part to a fixed value such as '2015-01-01' to see the result.

Comment: @mbo ModifiedDate is timestamp

Comment: **Well that was a waste of everybodies time.** Its always fun finding bugs in code that does not actually exist only to be told later thats not actually anything like the code I am actually running! I am thinking of a word to describe this, __but I cannot use it here__

Comment: sorry for that, but i've mentioned `if i remove date part i get records back to php` in comments section few mins ago. again ,apologies for wasting your time

Comment: I want to say Stackoverflow is so inefficient! We need a screen share collaborating service.